# How to get html td cell value by Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am trying to get the information from my table td's, using javascript. How can i achieve this? I have tried and failed, because i do not exactly understand the JS. So far, i have managed to get one of them to work, which is 'id' but thats just getting info from the db directly, the td values ive been unable to.

echoing the vals in my php update page shows the id val being passed successfully, but none others.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**

Per your last comment I can recommend you use an event listener on all `<td>` tags and this way you can just get the relevant text of the specific `<td>` that the user clicked:

```js
   var tds = document.querySelectorAll('td');
    for (var i = 0; i < tds.length; i++) {
     var td = tds[i];
        td.addEventListener('click', function(){
      console.log(this.innerText)
     });
    }
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
  <td class="awb">I am the first awb</td>
  <td class="awb">I am the second awb</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="differentClass">I am the first differentClass</td>
  <td class="differentClass">I am the second differentClass</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

---

You are approaching this all wrong...

Instead of this:

```
var awbno = String(tr.querySelector(".awb").innerHTML);
```

Do this:

```
var awbno = document.querySelector(".awb").innerHTML;
```

---

Here is a snippet:

```js
var awbno = document.querySelector(".awb").innerHTML; 
console.log(awbno);
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
<td class="awb">Test Text inside a td tag</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Cool, though *textContent* is likely a better property as it doesn't include any markup and the value should probably be URL encoded before being used in a request. ;-)

Comment: Added what you've shown be above, but the end result is the same as the original screenshot i posted. Could it be the repeated use of 'This'? td info isnt being picked up properly

Comment: @CS88 Please add an example of the html itself

Comment: Got it working! managed to echo all the values in the php update page.. only small hitch now is that date is being sent as DD-MM-YYYY, but for the DB, it has to be inserted as YYYY-MM-DD, so just need to change the format and should be working

Comment: also, the var awbno = document.querySelector(".awb").innerHTML; are getting the first record information of the td only?, say have 9 records, and i click to edit the 7th, the first records info is still being brought up in the php query, not the 7th

Comment: If you have multiple elements using the same class you should try a different approach.. You can use `this` to determine which one of the specific `<td class="awb">` was clicked...

Comment: See my latest edit.. maybe that is more like what you are trying to do

Comment: Not 100% confident with that loop, where about does it do within the function edit_user? or could you show me a snippet? It looks more or less on the track of what im trying to achieve

Comment: Sure try the snippet I just added... Just click on the `<td>`s

Comment: Okay, im understanding it, its scanning the record tds and creating an array tds[i] which then gets assigned to var td, but since var td is always getting rewritten, i wont be able to use in window.location.href..id=' + id + '&newAwb=' + awbno + would i?

Comment: The purpose of the for loop is to assign an onclick eventListener to each <td> so that when one is clicked, you'll have access to the specific one that was clicked.. Basically you could define what to do when either one is clicked.. Like create a request to the server each time a <td> is clicked on, and pass its values or even save each clicked <td> value to a separate var or object....

Comment: Ok, so can then update to db on <td> click, just one last thing, when i send var td to window.location.href... +td; and then echo that at the php update page (to see the value), its coming up [object HTMLTableCellElement], is this as it should be? anyway to get the value to come across/

Comment: no.. it's because you are sending the object.. you need to pass object.innerText which is a string

Answer (score 0):

in order to get the contents of any element using class

```
let value = document.querySelector('.className').innerHTML;
```

in order to get the contents of a specific TD

```
let value = document.querySelector('td.className');
```